# Why does a program (Dropbox) not load at system startup despite me checking that option in Preferences?

Tags: windows-7, dropbox

I'm working on a friend's computer (Win 7). My friend has the box ticked within Dropbox Preferences "Start Dropbox on system startup". Dropbox does not start up on system startup. However, it works fine if I start it manually later on.

My friend isn't fully informed about what the last person to look at his computer was doing, so it's possible some Windows settings have been altered without him knowing.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Run `msconfig` and switch to `Startup` tab, see if the Dropbox item is disabled.

Comment: If however it does not appear in the Startup tab, you can add a shortcut in this directory: C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu